# Customization of existing smart errors

Tags: google-smart-home

We have customized error messages that do not match well with the list of errors described on https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/errors-exceptions. Is it possible to add additional errors to Smart Home or customize existing errors in any way?

Answer (score 1):

The [errors](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/errors-exceptions) provided by the platform are tied to responses returned to the user through voice and touch Assistant surfaces. The platform does not currently provide a mechanism to customize these user-facing responses.

If you simply want to provide custom errors for the purposes of debugging, you can use the `debugString` field in an [intent response](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/intent/execute#response_format) to correlate this information in the cloud error logs for your project.